# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string' when using if else statement in C# for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to compare two strings if they are null or not null using && operator but I got an error saying "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'. In what way should I do this?
Here's my syntax:

```
else if((result1 != null) && (result2 = null))
```

My purpose is to check if a variable is not null and if it's null, the value would be stored in it instead of the other variables.

I found other questions like this but unfortunately they don't provide the solution for my need. :( Thank you for the help!

Comment: Don't know if it's a Unity thing, but = is an assignment and == is for comparison.

Comment: Oh yes yes, thank you oliver :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everybody's help! Unfortunately, using the line below didn't work like a charm.

```
else if((result1 != null) && (result2 == null))
```

Instead I used the following line and fortunately, worked!

```
else if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(result1) == false) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result2) == true))
```

Answer (score 7):

change this `result2 = null` to this `result2 == null`

the first one is assignment, not comparing

Answer (score 3):

You should do `result2==null` not `result2=null` that means assignment not comparison

Comment: Thank you thank you! I'm so sorry I am fully aware of that it's just I started with a single = and got confused. :(

Comment: That is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two boolean variables so you may do it like this

```
if(bool1 == bool2){ //do something }
```

But if you want to compare two strings so you must do by following line like

```
if(string1.equals(string2)) { //do something }
```

If you want to check whether a string is null or not so you can do it like this

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty("String here");
```

Here in your code

> else if((result1 != null) && (result2 = null))

I am assuming result1 is boolean and result2 is string so you must go like this

```
else if((result1 != null) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result2)))
```

Comment: Hi do you think using (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result2)) is the same as using string.IsNullOrEmpty(result2) == true)?